# jQueryUI draggable() and resizable() not working together in IE9

Tags: jquery-ui, internet-explorer-9, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-resizable

I'm trying to get .draggable() and .resizable() to both work on a certain  in IE9, but it doesn't seem to want to do both. 
So, I made a test page with a div with the class 'button' to find out what might be causing the issue. I feel like it should be working, but IE9 still seems to only want to enable draggable. 
The test page to demonstrate is
http://tanagerproductions.com/test/blank.html
I've tried clearing my cache and refreshing, and the object is still only draggable, not resizable. IE doesn't give me any js errors on the page either.
Can someone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: The source can be viewed from that test page, but also, here is the js code.
    
        
            
        
    
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.button').draggable().resizable();
        });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I didn't have the CSS file linked. So, to anyone else, make sure you have both the .js file and the .css file in your head for jQueryUI to work.